# Wash -i mon0 no output

Tags: networking, wireless, pentesting

I just swapped to Ubuntu 14.04 from Arch. I was installing some pentest tools from kali, the issue I'm having is when I run:

```
sudo wash -i mon0 -c 6
```

It has no output I'm only shown:

```
$ sudo wash -i mon0 -c 6

Wash v1.5.2 WiFi Protected Setup Scan Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>
mod by t6_x <t6_x@hotmail.com> & DataHead & Soxrok2212 & Wiire & kib0rg

BSSID              Channel  RSSI  WPS Version  WPS Locked  ESSID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

$
```

I am using a Alfa AWUS036H with rtl8187 chipset, wireless usb card. The card is in monitor mode, here is the output for iwconfig:

```
$ sudo iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

mon0      IEEE 802.11bg  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

I installed all the updates after installation. I added the Kali repositories and installed aircrack-ng and many other tools. Some of the tools I compiled and installed because the ones linked in the raring repository are out dated. Also installed pixiewps and the updated reaver with the pixie dust attack. Shortly after installing everything I ran the update once more and restarted.

After all that I went to test and the first thing I notice was the wash command shows no output and quickly exits. What would cause this on Ubuntu, didn't have this issue on Arch or kali. I thought maybe my test network picked it up again and switched channels on me like it did in the past but it didn't.

I also ran the wash command without specifying any channels to see if it was just my network not showing but it doesn't display any neighboring routers either.

Answer (score 7):

Another issue is that `wash` uses the directory `/etc/reaver` which is not created automatically. If wash shows an empty output check if the directory exists, if not `mkdir /etc/reaver`.

Comment: This worked for me after trying the answer from @jude and still getting the same

Comment: excellent, party on dude!

Answer (score 3):

i found the answer here https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?topic=666.0

this is not a reaver problem. This is output:libpcap0.8:i386 1.5.3-2, does not work for reaver/wash and must be downgraded to libpcap0.8:i386 1.4.0-2.

wget http://mirror.esc7.net/pub/Ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpcap/libpcap0.8_1.4.0-2_i386.deb

dpkg -i libpcap0.8_1.4.0-2_i386.deb 
restart mon0/wlan0mon